# Voice Recognition: Listening to specific voice commands

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Is there any way to listen to "specific" set of words in android? Which means, there is a list of voice commands like "Go", "Stop", "Up", "Down" etc. Android app should listen to only these words, not to anything else. All the tutorials I visited are teaching how to create an android app which listens to all the words.

Since this feature can be implemented in most of the other speech engines (for example in a PC using MS Voice API) I am sure this can be done in Android as well. But how can I do it?

Comment: The obvious thing is to just throw out any inputs that aren't in your list of approved words. If it's not on the list, just don't do anything.

Comment: @Geobits: I am sure there will be a problem. When the same trick is implemented in other engines, they misunderstand words a lot, because the dictation is wide. When specific dictation is added, this is not going to happen.

Comment: Assuming you're using the default voice recognition, it should return a list of possible words, not just one specific output. Check your list against each of these, and decided whether to accept it based on confidence level. I don't believe there's a way to say "only listen for `{"go", "stop", "up"}`".

Comment: Sorry, how do you suggest to `listen(listOfWords)`? Can you - a human being with natural intelligence - listen to only particular words without listening to all of them? I think that you can ignore the ones that you don't want to act on, but you can't stop listening (hearing) them...

Comment: @GermannArlington: Yes, they listen but they ignore. This method is implemented in natural language processing for "boost" the engine to hear to the "exact" voice commands. This is possible with PC engines, I have already done it

Comment: That's basically what my first comment said. Listen, ignore. The difference is with the Android recognizer, you have to implement the ignore part yourself. It's not built in.